# In languages which create a new scope each time in a loop block, a new local copy of the local loop variable is created each time in that new scope?

Tags: loops, scope, closures

It seems that in language like C, Java, and Ruby (as opposed to Javascript), a new scope is created for each iteration of a loop block, and the local variable defined for the loop is actually made into a local variable every single time and recorded in this new scope?

For example, in Ruby:

```
p RUBY_VERSION

$foo = []

(1..5).each do |i|
  $foo[i] = lambda { p i }
end

(1..5).each do |j|
  $foo[j].call()
end
```

the print out is:

```
[MacBook01:~] $ ruby scope.rb
"1.8.6"
1
2
3
4
5
[MacBook01:~] $
```

So, it looks like when a new scope is created, a new local copy of `i` is also created and recorded in this new scope, so that when the function is executed at a later time, the "i" is found in those scope chains as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively.  Is this true?  (It sounds like a heavy operation).

Contrast that with

```
p RUBY_VERSION

$foo = []

i = 0

(1..5).each do |i|
  $foo[i] = lambda { p i }
end

(1..5).each do |j|
  $foo[j].call()
end
```

This time, the `i` is defined before entering the loop, so Ruby 1.8.6 will not put this `i` in the new scope created for the loop block, and therefore when the `i` is looked up in the scope chain, it always refer to the `i` that was in the outside scope, and give 5 every time:

```
[MacBook01:~] $ ruby scope2.rb
"1.8.6"
5
5
5
5
5
[MacBook01:~] $
```

I heard that in Ruby 1.9, `i` will be treated as a local defined for the loop even when there is an `i` defined earlier?

The operation of creating a new scope, creating a new local copy of `i` each time through the loop seems heavy, as it seems it wouldn't have matter if we are not invoking the functions at a later time.  So when the functions don't need to be invoked at a later time, could the interpreter and the compiler to C / Java try to optimize it so that there is no local copy of `i` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the topic discussed here:  http://math.andrej.com/2009/04/09/pythons-lambda-is-broken/ .  In some programming languages, when you loop over a variable, the body of the loop construct is bound to one variable that increments.  In others, a new loop variable is instantiated per iteration of the loop.

As for lexical scope, note that in JavaScript, functions are the only constructs that form scopes (braces for `if`, `while`, `for`, etc. do not).  In C/C++, any pair of braces forms a scope.